# Cache Repository Service for C# IIS Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, caching, service

I would like to create windows service for my ASP.NET MVC web app which runs on IIS server, where this service work like Repository Caching loader, in the repository I have only static data, this is the reason, why I would like to cache this data for a long time (like 7 days = 24hx7d).

I am looking for some example, help, tutorial or the only simple way how to do it.

I want to service which wants to share cached data from the repository to each session from IIS Server to fast respond, Now I have a Repository loader and cache in-app, but I think then create service is the better solution.

I update static repository resources maybe 2 times per month

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why don't you use Redis instead of creating something like this.

Comment: Redis looks good, but for me is 3rd part app which I must still connect to my app via some additional lib into MS code, I looking for something that I want to implement myself, via pure Java, .NET or Pathon and after that, it will communicate easily with my IIS ASP.NET Web app

Comment: Which protocol, you want your IIS app to use to connect to the windows service.

Comment: I think then It does not matter for me, because communication will be only via web service and repository cache service than I want to set what I want, I think then REST Json will be the best option